# redis database for flask application

Tags: python, flask, redis

I am trying to modify an existing flask application to use a redis database instead of tokens. I searched for an example and through redis documentation but could not find anything. Here is what I have:

```
from flask import Flask, Response
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required

from redis import Redis
redis = Redis()

app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)


class User(UserMixin):
    # proxy for a database of users
    user_database = {"JohnDoe": ("JohnDoe", "John"),
               "JaneDoe": ("JaneDoe", "Jane")}

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.id = username
        self.password = password

    @classmethod
    def get(cls,id):
        return cls.user_database.get(id)


@login_manager.request_loader
def load_user(request):
    token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    if token is None:
        token = request.args.get('token')

    if token is not None:
        username,password = token.split(":") # naive token
        user_entry = User.get(username)
        if (user_entry is not None):
            user = User(user_entry[0],user_entry[1])
            if (user.password == password):
                return user
    return None


@app.route("/",methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return Response(response="Hello World!",status=200)


@app.route("/protected/",methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def protected():
    return Response(response="Hello Protected World!", status=200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "ITSASECRET"
    app.run(port=5000,debug=True)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction in terms of using redis as a simple authorization database?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of a specific suggestion, but there is pretty good documentation for [Flask-Cache](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/). It provides numerous ways to integrate Redis (or another cache) into a flask application. I am not sure if this will help you with your purpose, but in any case, it will eliminate some boiler plate.